# How to direct Google Chrome Rich Notifications to different monitor/screen?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, html5

I'm using Windows 7 at work with two monitors. I'd like to have my notifications appear on the screen that's not assigned as my desktop. Is there any way to do this?